# Username restrictions

Tags: support, display-names

Can one have any (nonduplicate) username?

What if one chooses username "jewhunter"?

There may be other names which are rather political or opinion, who decides on this?

Comment: Actually, people can have duplicate usernames, perhaps confusingly. The moderators of the site and/or the people who run SE have sometimes changed usernames in the past.

Comment: I would find any name which has almost purely racist/sexist/offensive meaning to be offensive. I am also not a fan of using names of actual people when it's clear you're not them (e.g. Bill Clinton) and that includes "slight typos" in that matter.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11562/how-permissive-should-we-be-with-user-names

Comment: But how do I *know* you're really the Asaf Karagila...$${}{}$$>.>$${}{}$$<.<

Comment: @Arkamis: You ask Arthur Fischer, Michael Greinecker, Gerry Myerson, amongst others.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe someone else was using your account in between..

Comment: emcor, unlikely. I'm almost constantly online.

Comment: See more here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8884/442

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are very few rules on user names, duplicates are explicitly allowed. But there are some restrictions:

- Impersonation of other users is not allowed (having the same name is not necessarily impersonation)
- The diamond symbol indicating a moderator can't be used in user names
- Offensive user names will be forcibly changed by moderators. The decision on whether a user name is offensive is made on a case-by-case basis by the moderators.

Comment: I expect it can be a difficult call, sometimes. Ages ago I met a female Iranian mathematician whose first name was Nazi. That might not work really well as a user name, though it is apparently a perfectly fine Persian name.

Comment: @Haran: According to a quick Wikipedia check there at at least two places in Iran called Nazi too.

Comment: What if a moderator has the name of another user? Does that mean the other user can't use their name? I would vehemently disagree with not allowing someone to use their name because some moderator shares the same name them.

Comment: @dustin Unless you're doing anything else to imply that you're a moderator or intentionally try to cause confusion, just having the same username as a moderator is no problem at all.